# How to Hide Array of Columns Based on Column Value(Todays Date)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'd like to achieve the following:

- Hide Columns starting from Column C up to the column that matches today's date(11/16/2022)
- Script should stop hiding columns if it reaches Column Z
- Apply this to 3 different sheets with same cell ranges (Sheet1, Sheet2, and Sheet3)
- I want to achieve this using Google Apps Script

Appreciate your help in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your situation, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```js
function myFunction() {
  const sheetNames = ["Sheet1", "Sheet2",,,];  // Please set your sheet names.
  sheetNames.forEach(sheetName => {
    const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
    sheet.showColumns(3, sheet.getMaxColumns() - 2);
    const today = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "M/d"); // or "MM/d" or "MM/dd"
    const num = sheet.getRange(3, 3, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getDisplayValues()[0].findIndex(e => e == today);
    if (num > 0) {
      sheet.hideColumns(3, num);
    }
  });
}
```

- When this script is run, from your showing sample image, the cells "C3:3" are searched by the date like `M/d`. When today's date is found, the columns until today are hidden.

#### Note:

- This sample script is from your showing sample Spreadsheet. So, when you change the structure of the Spreadsheet, this script might not be able to be used. Please be careful about this.

#### References:

- [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)
- [hideColumns(columnIndex, numColumns)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#hideColumns(Integer,Integer))

Comment: Thank you, you resolved my issue @Tanaike. I wanted to understand these sets of codes as well if how it works, please.  
sheet.showColumns(3, sheet.getMaxColumns() - 2);
const num = sheet.getRange(3, 3, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getDisplayValues()[0].findIndex(e => e == today);

Comment: @coders_key Thank you for replying. From `Thank you, you resolved my issue`, I understood that your issue was resolved. About your additional question, `sheet.showColumns(3, sheet.getMaxColumns() - 2)` shows all columns. `const num = sheet...` retrieves the number of hide columns by searching the cells "C3:3". If this explanation was not useful, I apologize.